# Postgresql recursion return an unexpected result

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to retrieve the entire employees hierarchy of specific manager.

The table is as the following:

```
id :: int
manager :: foreign key(users)
```

Data:

```
| id  | manager | 
-----------------
| 103 | 138     |
| 125 | 138     |
| 114 | 103     |
| 122 | 103     |
| 138 | NULL    |
| 144 | 222     |
| 222 | NULL    |
```

When I execute the following recursion:

```
WITH RECURSIVE managed AS (
        SELECT manager AS manager_id, id AS employee_id
        FROM users
        WHERE manager = 138
    UNION 
        SELECT u2.manager AS manager_id, u2.id as employee_id
        FROM users u2 
        INNER JOIN managed m ON m.employee_id = u2.id
    )


select *
from managed;
```

I received wrong result:

[image]

While the expected is:(exactly as the below link show...)

```
| employee_id  | manager_id | 
-----------------------------
| 103          | 138        |
| 125          | 138        |
| 114          | 103        |
| 122          | 103        |
```

I tried many examples include :: [this one](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-recursive-query/), which is similar to my question, but none of them worked...

When I tried to execute the query with `UNION ALL` the execution never ends(after several minutes I had to cancel the execution)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have small error - you need join on `m.employee_id = u2.manager` not `m.employee_id = u2.id`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE managed AS (
        SELECT manager AS manager_id, id AS employee_id
        FROM users
        WHERE manager = 138
    UNION 
        SELECT u2.manager AS manager_id, u2.id as employee_id
        FROM users u2 
        INNER JOIN managed m ON m.employee_id = u2.manager
    )


select *
from managed;
```

Result is:

```
 manager_id | employee_id 
------------+-------------
        138 |         103
        138 |         125
        103 |         114
        103 |         122
(4 rows)
```

Comment: I was sure that I had tried it... Thanks it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to find the employees hierarchy:

```
WITH managers AS (
    SELECT u.id
    FROM users u
    WHERE exists (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE manager = u.id LIMIT 1)
)
SELECT u.id as employee_id, m.id as manager_id
FROM users u
JOIN managers m ON m.id = u.manager;
```

->

```
 employee_id | manager_id 
-------------+------------
         122 |        103
         114 |        103
         103 |        138
         125 |        138
 (4 rows)
```

Comment: Hi @Gab thanks for the answer, however this won't solve my problem since it will return the entire company hierarchy(without the top level managers, those who has NULL managers). I'm trying to retrieve the hierarchy of specific manager. To return the company hierarchy I can do `SELECT * FROM users WHERE manager IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: Hi @OldFox I am a bit confused because you gave an expected result in your question and my answer fits your expected result. Can you please update the expected result if that's not the one you want

Comment: Hi @Gab I've updated my question; both the given dataset and the expected result.

Comment: I have slightly updated my answer and the result from my query is exactly the "expected result" from your question

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work... the answer will return `144 | 222` while it should not, since the user 222 is not part of the hierarchy for the user 138.